# Play a audio/sound in plsql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

In Plsql I want to create sound **(Beep)** while came to a particular exception.
I tried to search in many search engines but still I didn't get proper result and study material on this topic.
If any one knows about this, then this would be very helpful for me to make this functionality by using PLSQL itself.
Other option I have to call Java function to play audio file, this is my last option.
But in first hand I want to do this only with the help of PLSQL code, so that my code will not have any dependency on Java(or C or any other language).

Is it possible to produce sound in PLSQL code itself?
If anyone have  any idea, any suggestion, any start point or any study material .. please provide.

Comment: You want to play a sound with a **database** lanaguage?

Comment: You can't play sounds from databases, just like you can't chop and onion with a tire.

Comment: Even if that were possible - what it the goal of playing a sound on the DB server, is anyone sitting next to the DB server who could even hear the sound ? Does the DB server really have a sound card / boxes ?

Comment: @jnk chopping an onion with a tire is definitely possible although I would not want to eat the result...

Comment: @Yahia I think that would be CRUSHING an onion.

Comment: @JNK ok, that is right - "mashed/crushed onion" - perhaps this will be served sometime at McDonalds ?

Comment: People, just because it's probably not a good idea doesn't mean the question itself would be bad.

Comment: @Yahia : the sound can be played on the client calling the pl/sql. Same goes for dbms_output. Who is looking at the console of the database server? Does the server have a screen? ;-)

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth: yes I want to play sound with using database language..

Comment: thanks all for your idea ,,, 

but I thought this is also a feature provided by databas, which I don't know so that's why I asked .. is there no package available for this functionality ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`chr(7)` will produce a beep in SQL*Plus, at least on Windows:

```
SQL> select chr(7) from dual;
```

For those of you wondering why anyone would want to do this - I sometimes put that code at the end of long-running deployment scripts so it will beep when it's finished.

Comment: But it didn't produce any sound.. :( .. but i am looking for this kind of solution only... please check once again please..

Comment: Are you using SQL*Plus from the command line, or sqlplusw?  I've heard the sound from two different computers using the command line sqlplus.exe.  Also, try ctrl+g from the command prompt (not in SQL*Plus), that should also make a beep.

Answer (score 6):

This is so cool ;-). You *can* play sounds from the database.
The Talking Database – on putting query results into words – soundbiting from SQL?

http://technology.amis.nl/2011/01/the-talking-database-on-putting-query-results-into-words-soundbiting-from-sql/

Comment: great ....
but I think it will be taking so much of time as well as it need to be connect to internet ... right?
i don't have database in my lappy.. so that's why I couldn't test it.. but thanks .. if it works then it can solve some of my problem ..

Comment: This example needs a internet connection but you can store a mp3 on the server and retrieve that. But it's probably to far fetched for your needs. Just couldn't resist to show the database can make sounds some way or the other.